# Getting [object, Object] even after stringifying

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

So I have a node endpoint that fetches documents from mongodb. I am seperating data[0] and data[1] into variables because I want to do stuff with it and then chain both back into one varaible and send it.

code:

```
  const data = await Data.find();
  const data1 = data[0].api.results;
  const data2 = data[1].api.results;
   
  // Do stuff

  const response = data1 + data2;

  res.send(JSON.stringify(response)); // with and without JSON.stringify I still get [object, Object]
```

Note: both mongodb documents have the exact same structure. Everything works fine if I just send one variable so I think it has to do with JSON.stringify.

Comment: What should `data1 + data2` be producing? Because it seems it doesn't contain numbers or strings.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what "chain both back into one variable" means? I suspect you might want `const response = [data1, data2]` or something similar to that, but it's unclear.

Comment: i believe data1 and data2 are javascript object

Comment: @VLAZ it contains objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of what's being mentioned in the comments.

```js
const object_1 = { foo: { foo_1: true, foo_2: "test" }, bar: false };
const object_2 = { baz: "hello", bar: [ "one", "two" ] };

let result_1 = object_1 + object_2;
console.log(result_1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result_1));

let result_2 = [ object_1, object_2 ];
console.log(result_2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result_2));
```

Your issue has nothing to do with `JSON.stringify`. Adding the two objects together won't automatically format them for you.

Instead of `data1 + data2`, you will either need to stringify an array of the two objects `[data1, data2]` or [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/14956277) their properties into a single object.

Here's an example of a simple merge, but note that `bar` from `object_1` was replaced by `bar` from `object_2`. Make sure you handle intersections in your objects.

```js
const object_1 = { foo: { foo_1: true, foo_2: "test" }, bar: false };
const object_2 = { baz: "hello", bar: [ "one", "two" ] };

let result = { ...object_1, ...object_2 };
console.log(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: The second solution was the one. thanks!